# Control does not focus

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF user control with multiple child controls and I am focusing DataGrid and TextBox programmatically with the following code:

```
searchTextBox.Focus();
```

and

```
productGrid.Focus();

productGrid.Focus(dataGrid); //tried this but it does not help
```

searchTextBox focuses normally but dataGrid does not (keyboard focus stays on some other control). Below I provided full source code that hides searchTextBox and moves focus to productGrid (searchPanel is a parent Grid of searchTextBox):

```
    private void Execute_CancelCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (searchPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            searchPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            searchTextBox.Clear();

            searchTextBox.Background = Brushes.White;

            //the focus stays on the splitter for some reason
            productGrid.Focus();

            Keyboard.Focus(productGrid);
        }
    }
```

what can cause this situation?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that productGrid.`Focusable` property is set to `"false"`. You should just set it to `"True"` and your code should work correctly and there will be no need in calling `Keyboard.Focus()` method.

Comment: Please add comments *as comments* and *not* as answers. [Answers should ideally contain more than just two sentences](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: productGrid.Focusable is set to true (I checked it with debugger), but looks like productGrid focused partially because it highlights the selected row with blue rectangle, but dotted rectangle indicating keyboard focus stays on some other control. see http://slogpost.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/search-off.png, completely unfocused grid looks like this: http://slogpost.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/search-on.png

Comment: I'm not sure about the standard grid, but it is possible that it keeps focus on itself and handles keyboard events to navigate between rows etc. So if it's just a visual problem not behavioral I suggest you to   set DataGrid.FocusVisualStyle property to null in code(or to {x:Null} in XAML). 2Sankarann: sorry, I was sure that my idea is an answer to this issue.